# Calling stored procedures from Java - modern alternatives to Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

I've been using Spring JDBC's SimpleJdbcCall. I find very helpful, but still not simple and slick enough for me. Ideally I imagine a JDBC call not being distinquishable from an ordinary Java method call.

Seeing that many lightweight ORM frameworks have appeared in Java lately (e.g. Ebean), I wanted to ask if there is analogous development in the direction of stored procedures?

Comment: By the way ,i think that your own ORM is more faster than "complete" because many frameworks are trying to create next useless layer between application and database to prevent dependency on DMS. So my advice to you is create your own ORM and use methods that offer JDBC driver. Independency of application on DMS is bullshit i think.

Comment: @Sajmon: While I tend to agree with *"Independency of application on DMS is [...] i think"*, I tend to say that this assessment here: *"create your own ORM and use methods that offer JDBC driver"* will lead to great pain. There are a couple of tools out there written by people who have spent a lot of time thinking about how JDBC (and various drivers) work. Getting your own ORM right will take so much time...

Comment: I thing jooq is better

Answer (score 2):

#### Using JPA 2.1

Calling stored procedures from Java through JDBC or JPA can be very tedious and verbose. If you look a the [examples provided by EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21), things haven't gotten that much simpler with JPA 2.1:

```java
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name="ReadUsingMultipleResultSetMappings",
    procedureName="Read_Multiple_Result_Sets",
    resultSetMappings = {
        "EmployeeResultSetMapping", 
        "AddressResultSetMapping",  
        "ProjectResultSetMapping", 
        "EmployeeConstructorResultSetMapping" 
    }
)

@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "EmployeeResultSetMapping",
        entities = {
            @EntityResult(entityClass = Employee.class)
        }
    ),
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "EmployeeConstructorResultSetMapping",
        classes = { 
            @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = EmployeeDetails.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name="EMP_ID", type=Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name="F_NAME", type=String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name="L_NAME", type=String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name="R_COUNT", type=Integer.class)
                }
            )
        }
    )
})
```

#### Using jOOQ

A good option is to leverage a code generator, such as the one by [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) (I work for the jOOQ vendor, so this answer is biased). Assume this procedure:

```sql
-- Check whether there is an author in AUTHOR by that name and get his ID
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE author_exists (
    author_name VARCHAR2, 
    result OUT NUMBER, 
    id OUT NUMBER
);
```

Using generated code, you can simply call it as such:

```java
AuthorExists result = Routines.authorExists(configuration, "Paulo");
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1"), result.getResult());
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2"), result.getId();
```

See also the jOOQ manual for details:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/stored-procedures/
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/stored-procedures/oracle-member-procedures/

#### Using other code generators

Other code generators exist and can be leveraged to generate the tedious JDBC or JPA code.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to call stored procedures from JPA using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery and others.
You can use eclipselink for example. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/StoredProcedures

Hope it helps.